# Trying the TreeCtrl widget, getting a runtime error on exit

Tags: wxpython

I'm new to wxPython and am playing around with the TreeCtrl widget. I made this TreeCtrl test which has the following behaviour :
- Left click selects item, right click deselects it
- Children of item (if any) are automatically selected/deselected as well
It works as intended but I get a runtime error on exit :

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>      File "U:\python\wxpython\treectrl.py", line 49, in Propagate
>      state = self.tree.IsSelected(item)
>      RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type MyTree has been deleted

Here's my code :

```
import wx

class MyTree(wx.TreeCtrl):

    def __init__(self, parent, id, position, size, style):

        wx.TreeCtrl.__init__(self, parent, id, position, size, style)
        root = self.AddRoot('Root')
        i1 = self.AppendItem(root, 'Item 1')
        i2 = self.AppendItem(root, 'Item 2')
        i3 = self.AppendItem(root, 'Item 3')
        self.AppendItem(i1, 'Tomato')
        self.AppendItem(i1, 'Orange')
        self.AppendItem(i1, '42')
        i2_1 = self.AppendItem(i2, 'Sub Item 1')
        i2_2 = self.AppendItem(i2, 'Sub Item 2')
        self.AppendItem(i2_1, 'blah')
        self.AppendItem(i2_1, 'meh')
        self.AppendItem(i2_1, '...')
        self.AppendItem(i2_1, 'wut')
        self.AppendItem(i2_2, '1')
        self.AppendItem(i2_2, '2')
        self.AppendItem(i3, 'small')
        self.AppendItem(i3, 'medium')
        self.AppendItem(i3, 'big')
        self.ExpandAll()

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title,
                      wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size(450, 350))

        leftPanel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.tree = MyTree(leftPanel, 1, wx.DefaultPosition, (400, 300),
                       wx.TR_HIDE_ROOT|wx.TR_HAS_BUTTONS|wx.TR_MULTIPLE)
        self.tree.Bind(wx.EVT_TREE_ITEM_RIGHT_CLICK, self.OnRightClick)
        self.tree.Bind(wx.EVT_TREE_SEL_CHANGED, self.Propagate)

        self.Centre()

    def OnRightClick(self, event):
        item = event.GetItem()
        self.tree.UnselectItem(item)

    def Propagate(self, event):
        item = event.GetItem()
        state = self.tree.IsSelected(item)
        count = self.tree.GetChildrenCount(item, False)
        if count == 0:
            return
        else:
            (child, cookie) = self.tree.GetFirstChild(item)
            while child.IsOk():
                self.tree.SelectItem(child, state)
                (child, cookie) = self.tree.GetNextChild(item, cookie)



class MyApp(wx.App):

    def OnInit(self):
        frame = MyFrame(None, -1, 'TreeCtrl')
        frame.Show(True)
        self.SetTopWindow(frame)
        return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = MyApp(0)
    app.MainLoop()
```

I noticed when a TreeCtrl is created an EVT_TREE_SEL_CHANGED is automatically generated, so it's possible that event is also generated when the TreeCtrl is deleted but I don't know what to do about it. Although it could be something else.

Why is this happening ?

edit : running windows 7 with 4.0.3 msw (phoenix) wxWidgets 3.0.5 I haven't tested that with linux yet

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your suspicions are correct, although I have no such issue on Linux using '4.0.3 gtk2 (phoenix) wxWidgets 3.0.5'
Your best bet would be to check whether you actually have `item` i.e.

```
def Propagate(self, event):
    item = event.GetItem()
    if not item:
        return
    state = self.tree.IsSelected(item)
    count = self.tree.GetChildrenCount(item, False)
    if count == 0:
        return
    else:
        (child, cookie) = self.tree.GetFirstChild(item)
        while child.IsOk():
            self.tree.SelectItem(child, state)
            (child, cookie) = self.tree.GetNextChild(item, cookie)
```

Comment: That almost worked. I checked the existence of the TreeCtrl instead and that did it. Thanks for the suggestion !